# UDP packets sent from Rails on Heroku to HostedGraphite aren't accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, graphite

I have a Rails app on Heroku with code to send a UDP packet (on certain user actions) to HostedGraphite (I'm just trying out the free version).

I have pointed the "socket.send" call at my own UDP server hosted elsewhere, so I know that the UDP packets are being sent from Heroku.

I know that the API key from HostedGraphite is correct (checked this countless times).

I have also modified the format of the data being sent - including and excluding the "\n" at the end of the line (the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/hostedgraphite) specify to include the "\n").

I've also tried to send the packets from my development environment.

And then finally I've tried this:

```
echo "YOUR-API-KEY.test 1" | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003
```

My ruby code to send the packet is:

```
sock.send(data, 0, 'carbon.hostedgraphite.com', 2003)
```

Clearly from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html) Ruby's UDPSocket can handle a hostname instead of an IP address, so that surely is not an issue.

Ok it's possible that none of the UDP packets actually arrive...seems highly unlikely though.

Other than that I'm at a dead end and I don't know what else to try. Has anyone else used this service successfully (especially with a Rails app hosted on Heroku)? I'm starting to suspect that maybe I need to pay them money...

Next I'm going to rewrite it to POST to HostedGraphite (but I'm still putting up this question because it's UDP specific).

I also tried POSTing with a curl request (can't add any more links so you'll have to find the doc for that yourselves), and again, nothing appears on the HostedGraphite side of things (where you can do a search for your metrics).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as Too Localized because of the solution (temporary error with the service you are consuming), not because of question quality.

Comment: Same, the quality is fine, it's a little off-topic since it's not really a programming issue, but an issue with your hosted services. You can have an up-vote for putting effort into your question, but it's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Thanks dudes...I just kept thinking I must have been doing something wrong (programming-wise), hence the question. All good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We (Hosted Graphite) just fixed an issue affecting authentication for new users created in the last couple of days, and I think you were caught by this.

Sorry you had a poor first experience. We're adding alerting for that condition so it won't happen again.

I'm not sure how OK it is to provide commercial support in a forum like this, but we're pretty responsive to support requests over email and twitter, so give that a shot next time. :)

Comment: You are the man and I am a happy camper :D I only put a question here because on the support page it said I should exhaust help on community forums before contacting HG directly (and since I'm not paying I thought that only fair). Next time I'll drop you a line...thanks!!